# Counting the records in an object store in indexedDB not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I've been working on a project based on IndexedDB, and I have noticed that the method count() isn't working properly on Firefox. I don't know if I'm missing any concept, since I'm new to it, but I've tested it on Chrome and Opera, and it works perfectly.

A simplified version of the code is:

```
var database;
var openDB = indexedDB.open("newDB", 1);

openDB.onupgradeneeded = function () {
    database = openDB.result;
    var newStore = database.createObjectStore("example", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
    newStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
}
openDB.onsuccess = function () {
    database = openDB.result;
    var tx = database.transaction("example", "readwrite");
    var store = tx.objectStore("example");
    store.put({ name: "el_1" });
    store.put({ name: "el_2" });
    store.put({ name: "el_3" });
    store.put({ name: "el_4" });
    store.put({ name: "el_5" });        

    var transaction = database.transaction(['example'], 'readonly');
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('example');
    var counter = objectStore.index('name').count();
    counter.onsuccess = function () {
        total = counter.result;
        console.log(total);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except property result in the method count(), that returns 0, instead of 5. The database is created, and the objects are stored in the objectStore.

Comment: Thanks for posting a clear question and code to reproduce! I just ran your code in Firefox 65 and it says "5". What version of Firefox are you using, maybe it's older and there used to be a bug? Or maybe you inadvertently fixed a bug in your code when writing it up for Stack Overflow :P

Comment: @dumbmatter I just found the issue. It was me, and not Firefox. I'll post the answer in the comments. Thanks a lot tho! I wouldn't have realized otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. When I rewrote the code to post it here, I changed some things first to make it easier to understand. The problem was that my code used to be:

```
   var createStore = database.createObjectStore("example", { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
    createStore.createIndex("id", "id", { unique: true});
    createStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
```

And then:

```
    var counter = objectStore.index('id').count();
```

I guess that Chrome and Opera are okay with that, but Firefox doesn't allow it. ^^

Comment: Interesting, that does work differently in Firefox and Chrome! I'm guessing that Firefox is evaluating the index before adding the auto-incrementing key, and Chrome is doing the opposite. Not sure which is correct! But in practice probably nobody noticed this problem before because (as you probably figured out) it's not necessary to create an index on the primary key.

Comment: @dumbmatter That makes a lot of sense. Oh and the reason why I created it was that I wanted an element with autoincrement, so I could display the info in order with a cursor, and this way was very simple.  But now I know I shouldn't do it if I want it to be supported by Firefox :p

Comment: You can still do that without an index, just create a cursor on the objectStore directly. It'll use the primary key, which in this case is `id`.

Comment: @dumbmatter oh I see, I'll do that. Thanks!